# Check all images for put specific class on it then load slick slider

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have slider with slick slider on my page

First when the page load i check all images for give a class (If images is portrait or landscape)

Then I initialize slick slider

My jQuery code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('load', function(){
        $('img').each(function(){ // Here i check images
            var img = $(this);
            var width = img[0].naturalWidth;
            var height = img[0].naturalHeight;
            if(width >= height){
                $(this).addClass('paysage');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('portrait');
            }
        })
        
        $('#slider_sr').slick({ // Here i initialize my slider
            swipe:true,
            swipeToSlide:true,
            draggable: true,
            prevArrow:"<span class='prev_arrow'>&#9001;</span>",
            nextArrow:"<span class='next_arrow'>&#9002;</span>",
            asNavFor: '#slider_nav',
            dots: true,
        }); 
        $('#slider_nav').slick({
          slidesToShow: nbSlide,
          slidesToScroll: 0,
          asNavFor: '#slider_sr',
          dots: false,
          centerMode: true,
          focusOnSelect: true,
        });
    });
})
```

-----EDIT-------

```
    <div id="left_wrapper" class="wrapper_sr">
        <div class="wrapper_imgs">
            <div class="title_content_signle title_mobile">
                <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
            </div>
            <?php if($nb_slide > 0){ ?>
                    <div id="slider_sr" data-nb-slide="<?php echo $nb_slide; ?>">
                <?php foreach ($slider as $key_slider => $value_slider) { ?>
                        <div class="wrapper_img">
                            <div class="inside_img">
                                <img src="<?php echo $value_slider['photo_de_la_realisation']['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $value_slider['photo_de_la_realisation']['alt'] ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id="slider_nav">
                        <?php foreach ($slider as $key_slider => $value_slider) { ?>
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <div class="wrapper_thumbnail">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $value_slider['photo_de_la_realisation']['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $value_slider['photo_de_la_realisation']['alt'] ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <div id="single_wthout_img">
                    <img id="mon_image" src="<?php echo $thumb_sr; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>">
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is sometimes on firefox and edge images don't take class and the slider don't init as well. I never have this problem with chrome.

If the problem appears and I look at the firefox console, the js file is correctly executed.

So any idea why ?

How can i check if the images get class and how can i check if slider is initialized ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the HTML markup of your `slider_sr` and `slider_nav` elements in your question.

Comment: It is html with PHP because it is a wordpress site.
But this problem occurs randomly on firefox never on Chrome